# Calculate the duration in which a Prometheus metric had a certain value?

Tags: prometheus

Is it possible with Prometheus to calculate a duration (for example in seconds) in which a metric had a certain value?

A simple example would be an `up` metric which can have two values: `1` or `0` to indicate if a system is running. Imagine that since last week the system was going up and down several times.

I'd like to be able to calculate the total number of seconds the system was down during that period of time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the solution. To find the downtime (in seconds) over the last day:

`(1 - avg_over_time(up[1d])) * 60 * 60 * 24`

And here's how to use that query in Grafana to calculate the downtime depending on a selected time range:

`(1 - avg_over_time(up[$__range])) * $__range_s`

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54354010/274937) works only for `up`-like metrics, which can have either 0 or 1 values. If the metric can have other values, then the solution doesn't work :( In this case it is possible to use [subqueries](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/). For example, the following query returns an approximate duration in seconds when the metric `temperature` had values greater than 20 during the last day:

```
avg_over_time((temperature >bool 20)[1d:1m]) * 24 * 3600
```

This solution uses `bool` modifier for `>` operation - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators) for details.

P.S. VictoriaMetrics provides [share_gt_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#share_gt_over_time) function, which simplifies the query above to the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query:

```
share_gt_over_time(temperature[1d], 20) * 1d
```